# How to get further elaboration from someone who posted a good solution?

Tags: discussion, support

I just posted to request **(as a low-rep user; not a high enough rep to comment)** for a feature to ask a user on someone else's question, who posted a good solution, for further elaboration. My post was given a lot of criticism. Essentially, everyone deemed the request as abuse of comments. I understand their concerns, but know that others share the same frustration in addition to myself.

All I would like is a way to ask someone who posted a good answer to elaborate further. **Because I can't do this, I don't have a solution when there's a great one that's very close to helping me. If I post to ask the same question, that will be marked as a duplicate.**

I was on Stack Overflow and somebody posted a snippet of their code showing a great example that would have helped me quite a bit. But the code didn't show the whole picture, and if I could have had him elaborate on what he answered, I would have fixed my issue a while ago.

Nobody has provided a way to get further help, and I've seen so many posts that ask a similar question but haven't found a solution.

**So how can I ask someone who posted a good solution to elaborate further?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to settle for one of the following:

- Wait.  If the answer isn't clear enough, somebody else might be confused by it too and ask.
- Earn 20 rep and ask for further help in the site's chat room.
- Earn 50 rep and then ask your comment-question.

You said it's a good answer already, and you're asking for more help.  If what you're asking for goes well beyond the scope of the original question, then perhaps you have a new question.  (Search first, though!)

Comment: Only fourth point (ask new more detailed question) is a reasonable answer, all othe are not acceptable when user want to address a real problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Earn** enough [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) to post a comment, **never** use answers (especially on someone else's question) to **bypass the requirements** to make a comment. Requesting such a feature won't be well received.

If you can explain what was **not** asked and answered in *that* Q&A (which you didn't link to), and make a new question which is **not a duplicate**, that's one solution - you might earn enough reputation to comment and unlock other privileges.

Doing something equivalent to shoving into the front of the line and causing a disturbance (if that's a correct interpretation of your question) doesn't gain reputation, you're fortunate that you can't have less than 1 Rep.

Each site has its own help file located in the (?) Menu, [this site's help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) only applies here.

Comment: My previous question was requesting a feature. I highly doubt that feature is coming, so this question was asking for anything I can do that might achieve the same as that feature. Monica's answer clearly stated my options.

Answer (score 2):

If the existing question and answer don't answer your question, that means your question is different.

So I would post a new question, and explain how it is similar to the other question but not a duplicate.

Then, after you earn enough rep you could get the attention of the other question's answerer by requesting help in a comment on their answer, with a link to your question... Or maybe someone else will answer your question in the meantime. You never know.

Comment: This is actually the approach that seems closest to what I'd do here - especially considering the person posting the answer might not necessarily still be around, active or even working on the technology in question.